# ByteBuffer as CharBuffer

Tags: java, buffer, bytebuffer, charbuffer

I have the following code.

```
String s="AAAA"
ByteBuffer newBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
CharBuffer cbuf = newBuffer.asCharBuffer();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
         cbuf.put(c);
}
```

When I get the cbuf it's in the form 0 , 65 , 0 , 65 , 0 , 65 , 0 , 65.Why there are additional zeros in cbuf (CharBuffer)?

Comment: This looks like something to do with UTF-16 character encoding - chars are 16-bits in Java, bytes are 8-bit

Comment: *The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character* and 16 bits is 2 bytes. (E.g `A` in UTF-16 is `0x00 0x41`)